# How to pass deployment properties while scheduling a task through CLI

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

is there an example of how to pass deployment properties to a task schedule? I see an example of how to create a schedule through CLI:
dataflow:>task schedule create --definitionName mytask --name mytaskschedule --expression '/1 *'
I need to pass deployment properties to this. When I schedule through UI, I can give all properties in the text box, but unable to figure out how to pass the same through CLI. I tried --properties=<> but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `--properties '<props-string>'` where `<props-string>` is a comma-separated string of k=v pairs such as:

```
dataflow:>task schedule create ... --properties 'app.prop1=foo,app.prop2=bar'
```

There is also the `--propertiesFile` option if you want to put your properties into a file instead.